# Time div was create in multiple divs with same class, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I make a div (`.note`), by clicking on the screen, I have the time displayed in the div `.time`.

I can make as many of these as I want, but instead of displaying the time `.note` was created, is shows the time to tad was opened or refreshed.

How can I get `.time` to display the time `.note` was created?

```js
//$('.note').hide();
$('.note').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
$('#wrp, #wrapper').click(function showNote() {
  $('.note').fadeIn();
  $(".note").draggable({
    grid: [25, 25]
  });
});
$(function() {
  $(document).mousedown(function(event) {
    // only proceed if clcik is not anywhere in a note element
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.note').length) {
      var note2 = $('.note').first();
      note2.clone().insertBefore(note2);
      console.log(note2);
    }
  });
});
$('#wrapper').on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
window.onload = function() {
  var input = $("#item").focus();
};
function date() { //code indentation
  var now = new Date();
  now2 = now.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + now.getDate() + '/' + now.getFullYear() + ' ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
  $('.time').html(now2);
}
date();
var autosaveOn = false;
function myAutosavedTextbox_onTextChanged() {
  if (!autosaveOn) {
    autosaveOn = true;
    $('.item').everyTime("3000", function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/html/",
        data: "id=1",
        success: function(msg) {
          $('.msg').text(Saved);
          alert("saved");
        }
      });
    }); //closing tag
    console.log(myAutoSavedTextbox_onTextChanged);
  }
}
$(function() {
  $(".note").autoSave(callback, ms);
});
$(".item").autoSave(function() {
  var time = new Date().getTime();
  $("#msg").text("Draft Autosaved " + time);
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="wrp">
    <h1>Click to make a new note!!!</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="note">
      <p class="remove"><b>X</b></p>
      <div class="time"></div>
      <hr>
      <textarea class="item"></textarea>
      <div class="saved">
        <span class="msg"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjhind/zfxj3cps/48/))

Comment: Instead of trying to get around the warning and rule of posting your code in your question, in this case by highlighting CSS class names as code, please add your code to your question. Thanks!

Comment: I did!  I put the whole fiddle that I was using, and that has all the code in it!

Comment: The code should be *in your question*, not in a link in your question to jsFiddle. Sites like jsFiddle, jsbin, etc. should *supplement* the code in your question and never be the only source for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new note you're cloning the one that already exists - including the time that that note has; you need to insert the date at the time you clone it, as follows:

```
$(document).mousedown(function (event) {

    if (!$(event.target).closest('.note').length) {
        var note2 = $('.note').first();

        var now = new Date();
        var newTime = now.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + now.getDate() + '/' + now.getFullYear() + ' ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();

        note2.clone().insertBefore(note2);
        note2.find(".time").html( newTime );
        console.log(note2);
    }
});
```

You're now duplicating the date formatting code, this would be a function ideally that you can reuse in your code.

Comment: Thanks this worked, but how do I get the time to format just like the first one?